# Mimic webform date field in custom form

Tags: forms, datetime

In one instance we are using a webform to create a form and it uses field type 'date'. The end result looks like this:

[image: Webform date field]

I would like to mimic this, but in a custom form. Currently what I have is:
[image: Date field on custom form]

Code:

```
 $form['date_starting'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date_select',
  '#title' => t('Starting'),
  '#date_label_position' => 'within',
  '#date_format' => 'm d Y',
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have date_popup enabled you can achieve the calendar part by using this:

```
$form['date_starting'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#title' => t('Starting'),
  '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
  '#date_year_range' => '-3:+3',
);
```

Then you can style the input field as a calendar button and use javascript to copy the date value to your date select.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure how I would use javascript to get or pass that value